# How can I add Label several times in the same view - iOS8 [SWIFT]

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8

All is in the title : How can I add several times the same label in a same view.
I want display +1 when I score. But when I score two times during the action duration my game crash. I don't know how I can add 1, 2 or more times the same label.

```
addChild(labelScore)
let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 3), duration: 0.2)
moveAction.timingMode = .EaseOut
labelScore.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveAction, SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UIKit strictly enforces the rule that each view is only allowed one parent. As a result you cannot add the same label (view) to your UI multiple times.

What you need to do is create multiple label instance (perhaps with a for loop) and add these to your view.

Comment: Is there another possibility to display "+1" several times?